# Robocopy: copy files from local drive to SharePoint Online

Tags: migration, copy

I want to migrate files from local drives to SharePoint Online. Copying files with the Windows Explorer changes the file dates, which I want to keep.
My goal is to create a Batch file which helps the user to migrate the files to the cloud. The process needs to be as simple as possible for the enduser.

**Robocopy** does a good job by mirroring a complete folder BUT I can't connect it to SharePoint.

First I stumbled upon [this thread here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72265/robocopy-to-copy-files-from-an-old-sp-to-the-new-one). When trying to map or access the SharePoint directory the CMD prompt wants me to add the SharePoint to the trusted sites.

Then I found [this script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f73e7880-f573-443f-86ab-65a79ab60dab/robocopy-with-sharepoint-online) here BUT when I run it none of the commands is recognized nor do they work.

My current code is this:

`ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\XYZ1234\OneDrive\DEMO_SharePoint" "C:\Users\XYZ1234\Company\TestSharePoint - Dokumente\Robocopy Test" /COPY:DATO /MIR`

This copies the files to the synced SharePoint folder on my computer (and keeps the created date) but when they are uploaded the created date/time is equal to the copy date/time.

Now I'm stuck. Any ideas from the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is undoable, as Sharepoint's files metadata is populated when it is uploaded such as the (Creator, File Created Date, and Last Modified Date).

Comment: When I use robocopy the *Last modified* date is carried over to SharePoint. :-|

Comment: Yes, that is because "Last Modified Date" is referring to the "Last Modified Date" in Sharepoint, not on the local computer, I suggest not wasting anymore time pondering on this small issue as it will not affect anything else, if I helped, do mark my answer as the acceptable answer, thanks!